# Echo selected option

Tags: php, html

How would I echo a selected option in php?

I am using HTML to create a menu list (Buy and Sell), and I want to echo 'I want to buy the book' if someone choose "buy", or echo 'I want to sell the book' if someone choose "sell".

Comment: That can't be done with PHP. You have to use JavaScript or you have to submit the form before you can process the selection with PHP. I believe this was already explained to you [the last time you asked this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904442/print-selected-option).

Answer (score 2):

For the PHP to have access to the option in HTML, you're going to have to post the information from the HTML page back to the PHP.

PHP runs on the server; HTML is rendered on the client.  Despite the fact that you're writing the PHP and HTML in the same file, the actions taken by the user in the HTML on the client are not accessible to the PHP in the same script, unless you set the HTML up to post back the user's data to some PHP page (which can be the same PHP page).

Comment: Sorry Paul but I don't understand what u said. Here is my code.         <select name="buyandsell[]" size="1" id="buyandsell">
    <option selected="selected">value="0" Buy</option>
    <option>value="1" Sell</option>
  </select>

Comment: @Khoa: Your PHP is rendering HTML to be displayed to the client (browser).  Your browser is rendering HTML to be displayed to you.  Each rendering process is independent; the PHP code completes its rendering and exits before the browser begins displaying the HTML to you.

Comment: @Khoa the symtax of your HTML is invalid. `value="..."` should go within start tag `<option value="buy">Buy</option>`

Answer (score 0):

As said previously you will need to postback data from client (HTML) to server (php). This can be done in various ways but the most common are forms or Ajax.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <select name="option">
        <option value="buy">Buy</option>
        <option value="sell">Sell</option>
    </select>
</form>

<?php
If (isset($_POST['option']))
    echo 'I want to ', $_POST['option'], ' the book';
?>
```

Comment: Hey Lea your type are submit which are created 2 buttons Buy and Sell. I want to create a list with 2 option Buy and Sell and echo the option I selected.

Comment: I have only just realised that, the php is similar though @Khoa